# registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakeVideo()) is always null

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

I use the following codes for capturing video. Everything is ok but after capturing video, the  `registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakeVideo())` is always null. The captured video exists in the given path. In what ways I can resolve this issue?

```
 private fun openCameraForMovie() {
        val packageManager = requireContext().packageManager
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).also { takeVideoIntent ->
            takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                startRecording()
            }
        }
    }




 private fun startRecording() {
        try {
            val root = File(
                requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    .toString() + "/media/"
            )

            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdir()
            }

            val videoName = "vid_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4"
            val sdImageMainDirectory = File(root, videoName)

            var fileUri: Uri? = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                requireContext(),
                context?.applicationContext?.packageName + ".provider",
                sdImageMainDirectory
            ) ?: return

        
            mViewModel.videoUri.postValue(fileUri)

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Timber.d("startRecording ${ex.localizedMessage}")
        }
    }
```

This code is always null:

```
  private val recordVideoResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakeVideo()) { it ->
            try {
                if (it != null) {
                    Timber.d(">>>> Video Bitmap: $it") 
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Timber.d(">>>> Video Bitmap: ${ex.localizedMessage}")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What's happening?

> An `ActivityResultContract` to take a video **saving it into the provided
> content-`Uri`**.
>
> **Returns a thumbnail.**

Source [TakeVideo docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakeVideo), emphasis mine.

You don't want a thumbnail (which is optional anyway), you want the `Uri` that points to the actual video. But you already know the `Uri`, because you supplied it as the input.

#### Now what?

There are several steps required to make this work:

1. Store the input `Uri` in a variable and correctly handle saved state, so your app knows you've been recording video when you get back from the Camera app.
2. Write custom `TakeVideo` contract which returns if video capture was successful. Checking for non-null preview `Bitmap` cannot be used, because preview is optional.

It may look something like this:

```
private AtomicReference<Uri> recordingUri = new AtomicReference<>();

private ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> recordVideoResult =
        registerForActivityResult(new TakeVideo2(), success -> {
            final Uri uri = recordingUri.getAndSet(null);
            if (success) {
                // Do something with the video.
            }
        });

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        recordingUri.set(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("recordingUri"));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    // ...
    outState.putParcelable("recordingUri", recordingUri.get());
}

private void startRecording() {
    final Uri uri = // ...;
    recordingUri.set(uri);
    recordVideoResult.launch(uri);
}

public static class TakeVideo2 extends ActivityResultContract<Uri, Boolean> {

    @CallSuper
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Intent createIntent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Uri input) {
        return new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
                .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, input);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public final SynchronousResult<Boolean> getSynchronousResult(@NonNull Context context,
            @NonNull Uri input) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public final Boolean parseResult(int resultCode, @Nullable Intent intent) {
        return resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used your code, but the resultCode and Intent in the parseResult mehod is  -1,null. Taking pictures is working without any issue by using ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()

Comment: `TakePicture` also doesn't return the `Uri`, so you have to save it. Try modeling your `TakeVideo2` after [`TakePicture`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:activity/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.java;l=326?q=TakePicture&sq=&ss=androidx) (return boolean). If it returns true, use the `Uri` you saved earlier. Same as `TakePicture`. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I see, the `Uri` is only present in output if you didn't supply one as input. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE This makes it unusable with `TakeVideo`, which requires non-null input `Uri`. I will have to change my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you a lot.  you saved my day. It is working like a charm